# Proving every linear operator in the dual space is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces

How can I prove that for $X$ being a Banach Space, every $\phi \in X^*$ is compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounded operators with finite-dimensional image are compact and a bounded functional has rank at most $1$.

Comment: You would want to clarify that *bounded* finite-rank operators are bounded. There are rank-one unboudned operators, which of course are not compact.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer.

Comment: No problem. Of course my second "bounded" was supposed to be "compact" :)

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $(x_{n})$ is a bounded sequence in $X$, then $(\phi(x_{n}))$ is also bounded, then Heine-Borel Theorem implies that $(\phi(x_{n}))$ has a convergent subsequence, so $\phi$ is compact.